Meta Graph Api - Missing Previous Token For Previous Page
I'm using Meta Graph Api Explorer to test the Meta Ads API.
And the results look like this:
Request For First Page
When I add the after token into the request as a parameter, it doesn't return the token for the previous page:
Request For Second Page
here's the URL endpoint:
ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=['GE']&search_terms="A"&after= c2NyYXBpbmdfY3Vyc29yOk1UY3pNek0yTURRd01EbzRNakUyTnpZAMU9UTXpNVFl6T1RNPQZDZD

